# Why aren't these TextView next to each other?

Tags: android, layout, textview

I need to create multiple TextView dynamically next to each other. When I run the code below, the result is not what I expected. t1 and t2 are quite distant one from the other

```
RelativeLayout journals = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

    layoutUserDoes = new LinearLayout(this);

    layoutUserDoes.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(journals.getWidth() , 100));
    layoutUserDoes.setY(0);
    layoutUserDoes.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    journals.addView(layoutUserDoes);

    TextView t1=new TextView(this);
    t1.setTextSize(20);
    t1.setText("t1");
    t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    t1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    t1.setWidth(50);
    t1.setHeight(40);
    t1.setX(20);

    layoutUserDoes.addView(t1);

    TextView t2=new TextView(this);
    t2.setTextSize(20);
    t2.setText("t2");
    t2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    t2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    t2.setWidth(50);
    t2.setHeight(40);
    t2.setX(70);

    layoutUserDoes.addView(t2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put these two `View`s into a `LinearLayout` which makes it unnecessary to use the `setX()` method because this Layout will arrange its children automatically.

**So you now have 2 possibilities to fix this:**

1. remove the `t2.setX(70)` method invocation

OR

2. add the two `View`s to the `RelativeLayout` instead. The `RelativeLayout` will not arrange its children on its own so the `setX()` method becomes necessary again.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using :

t2.setX(70);

Answer (score 0):

try not to use `t1.setX(20);` and `t2.setX(70);`

the position of the views should be decided through it's parent

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setX`, it is preferable to use `RelativeLayout`'s alignment properties as you have RelativeLayout as parent layout. Skip the intermediate LinearLayout or change it to RelativeLayout.

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textView1Id);
textView2Id.setLayoutParams(params);
```

So your TextView 2 will be aligned to right of TextView 1.

Hope this helps.